# When printing values on separate lines in a loop, how do I avoid printing a newline after the last iteration?

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to loop through and print each element that is a prime number from a range of numbers. I want to print each of them in a new line, but no newline is needed at the end of the last element that is printed.

```
def prime_in_range():

    lower=int(input())
    upper=int(input())
    if 1 <= lower   <= 10000 and 1 <= upper <= 10000:

        for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
            # prime numbers are greater than 1
            if num > 1:
                for i in range(2, num):
                    if (num % i) == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    print(num)  #changing this to print(num,end='') prints everything in same line
prime_in_range()
```

With input as 1 & 10, I need the output as :

```
2
3
5
7
```

But I get a newline at the end by default

```
2
3
5
7
```

and get the below with `print(num,end='')`:

```
2357
```

Comment: I guess you want to concatenate the string and then print it out. The interpreter has no idea whether there will be prints in the future, thus it can't determine if you it should print the \n or not. You can also print \n at the start of the line. So the last line won't be ending with \n

Comment: `print` has no idea whether you're in a loop or not; but *you* can dynamically figure out whether you're on the last loop iteration and set the value for `end` appropriately.

Comment: I cannot run your code. Can you verify indentations?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Its running , There is no inf in console try to input. I was confusing too. :)

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik I get a bunch of indentation errors. I did change the function to accept two params and ditched the `input()` call

Answer (score 5):

A workaround is to make your function yield the output values, and make the caller unpack and print the values with newline as the separator with `sep='\n'`, and an empty string as the line ending with `end=''` instead:

```
def prime_in_range(lower, upper):
    if 1 <= lower <= 10000 and 1 <= upper <= 10000:
        for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
            if num > 1:
                for i in range(2, num):
                    if (num % i) == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    yield num

print(*prime_in_range(2, 7), sep='\n', end='')
```

Comment: You call it a workaround, I call it the correct solution. The function should be responsible *only* for generating/filtering the prime numbers. Printing is *not* its responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can store numbers in a list and then convert the list to a string separated by new line.

```
def prime_in_range():

    lower=int(input())
    upper=int(input())
    temp = []
    if 1 <= lower   <= 10000 and 1 <= upper <= 10000:

        for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
            # prime numbers are greater than 1
            if num > 1:
                for i in range(2, num):
                    if (num % i) == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    # print(num)  #changing this to print(num,end='') prints everything in same line
                    temp.append(num)
    print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in temp))
prime_in_range()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I tweaked the solution a bit to print the last item seperately and got the required results (not sure if this is the best solution yet):
P.S. Taking input from STDIN is mandatory, and not passing in the function call.

```
def prime_in_range():
    lower=int(input())
    upper=int(input())
    l=[]
    if 1 <= lower   <= 10000 and 1 <= upper <= 10000:

        for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
            # prime numbers are greater than 1
            if num > 1:
                for i in range(2, num):
                    if (num % i) == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    l.append(num)
                    #print(num)
                    #print(l)
    llen=(len(l))

    for i in range(llen-1):
        print(l[i])
    print(l[-1],end='')
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
7
Process finished with exit code 0
```